# execute command from Grails app

Tags: java, grails, groovy, process

I want to perform an `svn delete` from my Grails app. I tested out both of the following in the Grails console:

```
"svn delete /usr/share/mydir".execute()

Runtime.getRuntime().exec("svn delete /usr/share/mydir")
```

In both cases, a instance of `java.lang.Process` is returned, but the command does not get executed (`/usr/share/mydir` is not deleted).

This behaviour only happens when the app is running on Linux (Ubuntu). If I run it on Windows, the command does get executed.

### Update

Following Tim's advice in the comments, I changed the command so that it captures the process output:

```
def process = "svn delete /usr/share/mydir".execute()
def out = new StringBuilder()
process.waitForProcessOutput(out, new StringBuilder())

println "$out"
```

I now see that the reason it's failing is because:

> error svn: Can't open file '/usr/share/mydir/.svn/lock': Permission
>   denied

Comment: `waitForProcessOutput` and piping to the usual locations not revealing what it's doing instead of running?

Comment: This seems a subversion issue (due to earlier incomplete changes). Could you run a svn clean operation on this repository first.

Comment: For portability's sake, I'd suggest http://svnkit.com/ for interfacing directly with svn from Java via it's API instead of starting a process.

Comment: Facing the same issue, any updates here?

Answer (score 3):

The below code works fine for me on CentOS.

```
    def scriptCom="/folderlocation/shellscript.sh"
    println "[[Running $scriptCom]]"
    def proc = scriptCom.execute()

    def oneMinute = 60000
    proc.waitForOrKill(oneMinute)

    if(proc.exitValue()!=0){
        println "[[return code: ${proc.exitValue()}]]"
        println "[[stderr: ${proc.err.text}]]"
        return null
    }else{
        println "[[stdout:$revisionid]]"
        return proc.in.text.readLines()
    }
```